# Lamp and eeevee volumetric light. How to avoid the halo around the light source

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am using volumetric light with Eevee and I have no idea to avoid the halo around the source of my light.

[image]

I can locate my cube with volume scatter under the lamp but I want to have volumetric light for my whole scene.

I changed start in volumetrics but I am not fully satisfied with the result.

[image]